# Can one get a mouse for the console?

Tags: software-recommendation, mouse, console

Although I mostly have no use for a mouse in the console, and I go there to get away from the GUI, I would like to know if there is some sort of mouse that one can get in there? So is there like any software which will give me a mouse in there so that I can select text etc? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GPM** is just the application you are looking for! It stands for "General Purpose Mouse":

```
 This package provides a daemon that captures mouse events when the system
 console is active, and delivers events to applications through a library.
 .
 By default, the daemon provides a 'selection' mode, so that
 cut-and-paste with the mouse works on the console just as it does
 under X.
```

And can be installed by running:

```
sudo apt-get install gpm
```

---

**Screenshot:**

[image: General Purpose Mouse in action]

**FYI:** I have put a red box around the mouse just to make it obvious where and what it is. I have also selected some text above just to show that this can be done.

Comment: You may need to start the service manually after installation. This was necessary on Ubuntu 18.04.