# CTL V or H fails in NANO

Tags: nano, paste

Used to be I could copy outside of nano and within NANO paste.  That is failing now on my install. I have a current linux on a Lenovo laptop.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is not paste in nano, or most other terminal applications.

Nano's [own manual](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.0/nano.html) is a good read regarding keyboard shortcuts in nano, and most of them are displayed at bottom of screen. Note that `^` generally means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, so `^v` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

You can also press `^g` to get help in nano. This will give you a overview of functionality and key combinations that you can use within the editor.

To cut a line in nano, use `^k`, and paste it with `^u`. You can also paste into a terminal using middle click, or your terminal emulators paste function.

`^v` is next page in nano, and `^h` is backspace (delete character to the left of the cursor).

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788932/how-to-paste-commands-into-a-tty) covers how to paste into a terminal.